# Clojurescript - Codox documentation for Om components

Tags: clojure, documentation, clojurescript

I am generating Codox documentation for a Clojurescript webapp.  Here's an example function that I'll use to demonstrate my issue:

```
(defn breadcrumbs
  "Render Breadcrumbs"
  [app owner]
  (om/component
    (let [crumbs (:breadcrumbs app)]
      (dom/div #js {:id "breadcrumbs"}
        (when (> (count crumbs) 0)
          (apply dom/ol #js {:className "breadcrumb os-border-default"}  
              (om/build-all breadcrumb crumbs)))))))
```

The problem is that using om/component causes Codox to generate documentation for four additional "hidden" functions (presumably these are the IRender, IDidUpdate, etc functions that can be defined for a component...but I'm not sure).  In the documentation these functions look like this:

->t6127
(->t6127 crumb breadcrumb meta6128)

->t6130
(->t6130 crumb breadcrumb meta6131)

->t6133
(->t6133 owner app breadcrumbs meta6134)

->t6136
(->t6136 owner app breadcrumbs meta6137)

This unneeded documentation is greatly cluttering up the final product.  I know individual functions can be skipped via "^:no-doc" but there doesn't seem to be a way to use that here.

Has anyone else experienced this and know how to get rid of the clutter?

Answer (score 1):

Codox currently has problems with `reify` in ClojureScript, which is used internally by `om/component`.

David Nolen suggested that the information to distinguish these temporary values should be available in current versions of ClojureScript via the analyzer, but I haven't been able to find it, and no-one's been able to point me to it. See issue [#72](https://github.com/weavejester/codox/issues/72) on the Codox project page for more information.

Comment: This issue has now been fixed in Codox 0.8.11.

Answer (score 0):

`om/component` is a very simple [macro](https://github.com/omcljs/om/blob/master/src/om/core.clj) that generates only `render` for `IRender`. It looks like Codox is giving you two functions for `breadcumb` (first two) and two for `breadcumbs`. One is probably the one you want and the other one is from `render`. You could either write your components like this:

```clj
(defn breadcrumbs
  "Render Breadcrumbs"
  [app owner]
  (reify
    om/IRender
    (render ^:no-doc [_]
      (let [crumbs (:breadcrumbs app)]
        (dom/div #js {:id "breadcrumbs"}
          (when (> (count crumbs) 0)
            (apply dom/ol #js {:className "breadcrumb os-border-    default"}  
                (om/build-all breadcrumb crumbs)))))))
```

or write your own `no-doc-component` macro:

```clj
(defmacro no-doc-component
  [& body]
  `(reify
     om.core/IRender
     (~(vary-meta 'render assoc :no-doc true) [this#]
       ~@body)))
```

Disclaimer: although I've tried the macro, I haven't tried it with Codox.

Comment: Thanks.  This sounds like it would work but I tried it and it doesn't.  The breadcrumbs function actually generates 3 functions in Codox.  One is correct and the other 2 are the garbage "->t6133" and "->t6136" things I posted above.

Comment: Ok. After some digging, I found [this](https://github.com/weavejester/codox/issues/72). It seems to be a known issue between Codox and `reify`.

Answer (score 0):

weevejester fixed this issue in version 0.8.11.

He also configured the ClojureScript analyzer to not analyze dependencies which allows me to generate docs for my Om projects. It should also reduce the number of namespaces in the :exclude configuration. Mine has been reduced to 0.